# Finding other solutions for an ODE $ y=2\sqrt{x} - (y')^2/(2y'')$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ y(x) $ be a funtion defined on $[0,\infty)$ which satisfies
$$
y=2\sqrt{x}-\frac 12 \frac{(y')^2}{y''}.
$$

One can check that 
$$
y=4\sqrt{x}
$$
is a solution of this ODE.

For a second order ODE, it has two (general) solutions.
So can we find other solutions for this ODE?

Comment: @LostInSpace Thank you for your comment, I have corrected.

Comment: Just for the curiosity, what made you to think it has two solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside its domain, an ODE has a solution for every initial condition. Here the initial conditions at $x=0$ form a 2-dimensional state space.

But the equation is not linear, thus you get no basis solutions, as linear combinations of solutions do not give other solutions. So it makes no sense to ask for a second basis solution.